# why my node-red connection disconnetct while running the python using mqtt program?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt

This is my node-red flow, every time i run the program they will disconnect.
and this is my python program

```
import cv2
import utilis
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time 

#####MQTTprogram

broker_address="192.168.1.105"
client_id = "measurement"
print("Quality Control")
print("Qualty Control Mesin Press", client_id)
client = mqtt.Client(client_id)
print("Mencoba koneksi ke MQTT Broker")
client.connect(broker_address)
###################################

webcam = True
path = '/home/pi/Downloads/Real-Time-Object-Measurement-master/1.jpg'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(10,160)
cap.set(3,1920)
cap.set(4,1080)
i = 0
j = 0

###################################

while True:
print ("Memulai Pendataan")
msg_topic="Polman/TA/MonitoringMesinPress"
if webcam:success,img = cap.read()
else: img = cv2.imread(path)
imgContours , conts = utlis.getContours(img,minArea=2000,filter=4, cThr=[50,50],draw = False)
if len(conts) != 0:
biggest = conts[0][2]
    #print(biggest)
imgWarp = utlis.warpImg(img, biggest, wP,hP)
for obj in conts:
cv2.polylines(imgContours,[obj[2]],True,(0,255,0),2)
nPoints = utlis.reorder(obj[2])
nW = round((utlis.findDis(nPoints[0][0]//scale,nPoints[1][0]//scale)/10),1)
nH = round((utlis.findDis(nPoints[0][0]//scale,nPoints[2][0]//scale)/10),1)
cv2.arrowedLine(imgContours, (nPoints[0][0][0], nPoints[0][0][1]), (nPoints[1][0][0], nPoints[1][0][1]),(255, 0, 255), 3, 8, 0, 0.05)
cv2.arrowedLine(imgContours, (nPoints[0][0][0], nPoints[0][0][1]), (nPoints[2][0][0], nPoints[2][0][1]),(255, 0, 255), 3, 8, 0, 0.05)
x, y, w, h = obj[3]
cv2.putText(imgContours, '{}cm'.format(nW), (x + 30, y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1.5,
                        (255, 0, 255), 2)
 cv2.putText(imgContours, '{}cm'.format(nH), (x - 70, y + h // 2), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1.5,
                        (255, 0, 255), 2)
print (i, nW)
print (j, nH)
    ##Loop Program
 client.loop_start()
  while True :
for i in range(10):
if (i>4):
msg_value = 10-i
else :
msg_value = i
for j in range(10): 
 if (j>4):
    msg_value = 10-j
else :
    msg_value = j
print ("Mem-publish ke broker MQTT pada topic", msg_topic, "dengan nilai", msg_value)
client.publish(msg_topic, msg_value)
time.sleep(1)

img = cv2.resize(img,(0,0),None,0.5,0.5)
cv2.imshow('Original',img)
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: There is no where enough information (No Node-RED Flow, logs from MQTT broker) here to help, but first guess is that you have set the same MQTT client id in both Node-RED and your python code.

Comment: Yup, i was setting the client id and topic the same as in the python @hardillb